# Angular : manage several unlimited identical form on one page

Tags: angular, forms

I need to have a page with a form and a button "add" which create one more exact same form (empty one)

I've been struggling with different problems. Here's what I ve done so far:

```
<form>
    <div *ngFor="let car of cars; let i = index">
    <label>Brand</label>
    <input #text="ngModel" type="text" name="brand[i]" [(ngModel)]="car.brand">
    <label></label>
    <input #text="ngModel" type="text" name="size[i]" [(ngModel)]="car.size">
</div>
<button type="button" (click)="onAddCar(form)">Add Car</button>
</form>
```

my tsFile is something like:

```
cars : Car[] = [];
myFirstCar = new Car();
myFirstCar.brand = '';
myFirstCar.size = '';
cars.push(myFirstCar);


ngOnInit{
     this.carService.getCars() .subscribe(response => { this.cars= response; });
}
onAddCar() {
    myNewCar = new Car();
    myNewCar.brand = '';
    myNewCar.size = '';
cars.push(myNewCar);
```

Here are my problems:

- when I get my cars on Init. No matter how big is my list, the same car is displayed all the time
- when I press add Car, all the fields get set to null instead of keeping what I ve done so far.

How could I do ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate the display of the list of your cars and the input.

> when I get my cars on Init. No matter how big is my list, the same car is displayed all the time

You want to check if your carService.getCars() method is actually returning anything. You also have a space between .getCars() and .subscribe

> when I press add Car, all the fields get set to null instead of keeping what I ve done so far.
>   In your code, you're trying to pass "form" to the method. But the signature of your onAddCar() method takes no parameter at all.

Here's how I would change your code. It's not perfect, but I think it's useful to you.
In the HTML template:

```
<form>
    <div *ngFor="let car of cars;">
        <label>Brand</label>
        <input type="text" name="carbrand" [value]="car.brand">
        <label></label>
        <input type="text" name="carsize" [value]="car.size">
    </div>
</form>

<input type="text" name="carbrand" [(ngModel)]="brand">
<input type="text" name="carsize" [(ngModel)]="size">
<button type="button" (click)="onAddCar(brand, size)">Add Car</button>
```

In the ts file:

```
cars : Car[] = [];
brand:string = '';
size:string = '';
ngOnInit(){
    this.carService.getCars().subscribe(response => { this.cars= response; });
}

onAddCar(brand:string, size:string) {
    var myNewCar = new Car(brand,size);
    this.cars.push(myNewCar);
}
```

I hope it helps.